# cannot able to create new page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "post_content" on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\puneet\wordpress\wp-admin\includes\post.php:787 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\puneet\wordpress\wp-admin\post-new.php(66): get_default_post_to_edit('page', true) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\puneet\wordpress\wp-admin\includes\post.php on line 787

please help me to create new page in wordpress and provide me a solution